# Virutally loading website, running actions, reloading

Tags: javascript, c++, windows, cmd

I'm trying to program a way for a command prompt using something like C++ to load a webpage, locate a string of text, click two buttons next to that string, reload then repeat. Yet, I am lost at where to begin? Whats the best language I could use to go about this efficiently? Thanks

Comment: You might be mistaking javascript for java. Javascript is run inside browser environments generally. Java can be compiled and run like an actual program.

Comment: Sorry, I assumed JavaScript was something else! I shouldn't have said that being unfamiliar with JavaScript yet familiar with java, thanks for the feedback

Comment: No problem, it's a common mistake for those not familiar with it. As for your question, it's somewhat opinionated. You can use many languages to accomplish that. C++, Java, Python, etc.